# Using template types with arguments initialized

Tags: c++, templates

How can I use a template class where I can call a constructor with some default arguments? Is this possible?

Ex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class HoHoHo {
public:
    HoHoHo<T>(T yell);
    template <class TT> friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const HoHoHo<TT> &);
private:
    T yell;
};
template <class T> HoHoHo<T>::HoHoHo(T yell) {this->yell = yell;}
template <class T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &o, const HoHoHo<T> &val){ return o << "HoHoHo " << val.yell << "."; }

class Cls{
public:
    Cls(int a=0, int b=0);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Cls &);
private:
    int a;
    int b;
};
Cls::Cls(int a, int b){ this->a = a; this->b = b; }
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &o,  const Cls &val) { return o << val.a << "," << val.b; }

int main()
{
  Cls cls(2,3);
  HoHoHo<Cls> hohoho(cls);
  cout << hohoho << endl; //This prints "HoHoHo 2,3"

  //DO NOT WORK
  HoHoHo<Cls(3,4)> hohoho_test(); // Want something like this?
  cout << hohoho_test << endl; // to print "HoHoHo 2,3"

  return 0;
}
```

Here I would like to be able to call the constructor of the template class with some default values. How do I achieve something like this?

I can write another class to encapsulate, but hoping there's a more clever solution.

---

I guess the way to do this IS encapsulation. thx @jive-dadson

```
template<int A, int B> class Cls_ext: public Cls {
public:
    Cls_ext<A,B>(){ this->a = A; this->b = B;}
};
```

and

```
  HoHoHo<Cls_ext<3,4> > hohoho_test; 
  cout << hohoho_test << endl; // prints "HoHoHo 3,4"
```

Comment: *"Looking for a general solution for a custom class that uses templates"* It is very unclear what you mean by that.

Comment: Read a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282)

Comment: @PasserBy, damn, never thought about reading a book!

Comment: I can't tell if you're being sarcastic. Any good book will cover this content.

Comment: BTW, prefer initializers (`Cls::Cls(int a, int b) : a{a}, b{b}  {}`) to writing assignments an the constructor.

Comment: @TobySpeight, yeah, just that it gave me an error with `Cls_ext<A,B>(): a(A), b(B) {}`, so reverted back for both. Guess you can't do that with template params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking, but maybe the template below is what you want. Notice that template parameters go in angled brackets <>, not parentheses.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<int A, int B>
class Cls{
public:
    Cls(): a(A), b(B) { }
    void Print(){ std::cout << a << "," << b << std::endl; }
private:
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Cls<3,2>> vec(5); //Something like this?
  vec[0].Print(); // Should print "3,2"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` has a special constructor for repeating an element N times:

```
std::vector<Cls> vec(5, Cls(3,2));
```

Comment: That's good to know :) though I am actually looking for a general solution since I need it for a custom class that uses templates :/

Comment: @xcorat Then I think you need to restate your question. General how?

Comment: @xcorat It's not, at least to me. How using a template stops you from using this techinque? Something like `std::vector<my_class<int>> vec(5, my_class<int>(1,2));` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This line makes no sense, as `HoHoHo` requires a *type* template parameter:

```
  HoHoHo<Cls(3,4)> hohoho_test();
```

I think you meant:

```
  HoHoHo<Cls> hohoho_test(Cls(3,4));
```